Hidden Markov Model Likelihood when Marginal Density Isn't avaliable?
The question might be trivial or non-sensical but help me understand, please.
My understanding so far:

The likelihood is given by
$$
L_T=\boldsymbol{\delta \text{P}}(x_1)\boldsymbol{\Gamma \text{P}}(x_2)\boldsymbol{\Gamma \text{P}}(x_3)\ldots\boldsymbol{\Gamma \text{P}}(x_T)\boldsymbol{1'},
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\delta}$ is the initial distribution, $\boldsymbol{\text{P}}(x)$ is a dagonal matrix with $i$'th diagonal element $f_i(x)$; the probability density function of $X_t$  associated with state $i$ (state-dependent distribution) and $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}$ the transition probability matrix.
The HMM is constructed such that the observations are conditionally independent of each other but not unconditionally meaning the Markov chain
induces dependence in the state dependent process, i.e. the observations are only independent of each other within states.
However, my model, does assume dependence. Furthermore, it is well known that the conditional density / transition density from $t-1$ to $t$ is a decentralised chi-square distribution.

My question is then, Assume $S_t=i$ denotes the state at time $t$ is $i\in\{\text{# of states}\}$. Is it possible to directly replace the state-dependent distributions in $\boldsymbol{\text{P}}(x)$ by
$$
f_i(x_t)=f(x_t\mid x_{t-1},S_t=i)
$$
rather than
$$
f_i(x_t)=f(x_t\mid S_t=i)
$$
or is this non-sensical?

This is a very sensible model in many situations where the autocorrelation in the observation process is stronger than what can be induced by the state process alone. It is sometimes called an autoregressive hidden Markov model (e.g., Zucchini et al., 2017, Section 10.4).
The short answer is that you can still use the likelihood expression that you mention, except where each matrix $P$ depends on two successive observations.
To see this, we can go over the derivation of the likelihood in that form. First, notice that, by the law of total probability,
$$
L_T = f(X_1 = x_1, \dots, X_T = x_T) = \sum_{i\in \mathcal{S}} f(X_1 = x_1, \dots, X_T = x_T, S_T = i)
$$
where $f(...)$ denotes either a probability or a probability density, and where $\mathcal{S}$ is the state space of the Markov process. It is then convenient to define the forward variable $\alpha_k^{(m)} = f(X_1 = x_1, \dots, X_m = x_m, S_m = k)$, such that $L_T = \sum_i \alpha_i^{(T)} = \boldsymbol\alpha^{(T)} \boldsymbol{1}'$. There is a convenient iterative method to get $\boldsymbol\alpha^{(m)}$ from $\boldsymbol\alpha^{(m-1)}$ (sometimes called the forward algorithm).

For $m = 1$:
$$
\alpha_k^{(1)} = f(X_1 = x_1, S_1 = k) = f(X_1 = x_1 \mid S_1 = k) Pr(S_1 = k) = f_k(x_1) \delta_k
$$
using the notation from your post where $f_k(x) = f(X_m = x \mid S_m = k)$ and $\boldsymbol\delta$ is the initial distribution of the Markov chain. In matrix notation:
$$
\boldsymbol\alpha^{(1)} = \boldsymbol\delta \boldsymbol{P}(x_1).
$$
Note that in your example, computing $\boldsymbol{P}(x_1)$ might also require a previous observation, say $x_0$, so I will replace it by $\boldsymbol{P}(x_0, x_1)$ below.

For $m > 1$, using the law of total probability and subsequently taking advantage of conditional independence assumptions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha_k^{(m)} & = \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} f(X_1 = x_1, \dots, X_m = x_m, S_m = k, S_{m-1} = i) \\
& = \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} f(X_m = x_m \mid X_{m-1} = x_{m-1}, S_m = k) f(X_{m-1} = x_{m-1}, \dots, X_1 = x_1, S_m = k, S_{m-1} = i) \\
& = \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} f_k(x_m \mid x_{m-1}) Pr(S_{m} = k \mid S_{m-1} = i) f(X_{m-1} = x_{m-1}, \dots, X_1 = x_1, S_{m-1} = i) \\
& = \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} f_k(x_m \mid x_{m-1}) \gamma_{ik} \alpha_i^{(m-1)}
\end{aligned}
$$
The main difference with the regular hidden Markov model is in the second line above, where $f_k(x_m \mid x_{m-1}) = f(X_m = x_m \mid X_{m-1} = x_{m-1}, S_m = k)$ would usually simplify further to $f_k(x_m) = f(X_m = x_m \mid S_m = k)$. But the rest of the derivation still stands. In matrix form, this gives us:
$$
\boldsymbol\alpha^{(m)} = \boldsymbol\alpha^{(m-1)} \boldsymbol\Gamma \boldsymbol{P}(x_{m-1}, x_m)
$$
where $\boldsymbol{P}(x_{m-1}, x_m)$ is the diagonal matrix with $k$-th diagonal element equal to $f_k(x_m \mid x_{m-1})$.


We can use this relationship to find $\boldsymbol{\alpha}^{(1)}, \boldsymbol{\alpha}^{(2)}, \dots, \boldsymbol{\alpha}^{(T)}$, which yields:
$$
\boldsymbol\alpha^{(T)} = \boldsymbol{\delta} \boldsymbol{P}(x_0, x_1) \boldsymbol\Gamma \boldsymbol{P}(x_1, x_2) \dots \boldsymbol\Gamma \boldsymbol{P}(x_{T-1}, x_T)
$$
and so
$$
L_T = \boldsymbol{\delta} \boldsymbol{P}(x_0, x_1) \boldsymbol\Gamma \boldsymbol{P}(x_1, x_2) \dots \boldsymbol\Gamma \boldsymbol{P}(x_{T-1}, x_T) \boldsymbol{1}'.
$$
References
Zucchini, W., MacDonald, I. L., & Langrock, R. (2017). Hidden Markov Models for Time Series: An Introduction Using R. CRC Press.

Thanks a ton for the response. I used your package momentuHMM the very first time I got to know the concept. Could I perhaps contact you privately regarding a study inquiry?

Glad it helped -- sure, feel free to get in touch.

Great! It is send.
